# LuaLaTeX and PSTricks

Tags: luatex, pstricks

Is there the possibility to produce PSTricks graphics in LuaLaTeX?

I tried it, but i get

```
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 

    l.9 \psline(
        -5,2)(5,4)
```

With `auto-pst-pdf` I get a warning to use pdflatex.

So how can i use pstricks in LuaLaTeX?

Edit:@Marco Daniel

I asked where to pack packages for specified for lualatex, "normal packages", and pstricks packages:
Maybe something like this:

```
    \RequirePackage{ifluatex}
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \ifluatex
        \usepackage{fontspec}
        \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
        \usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
    \else
         \usepackage{pstricks}
         \usepackage{pst-plot}
    \fi
         \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
    \begin{document}
    Here text...
    \end{document}
```

Niklas

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). PLease see: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput

Comment: Thanks! That works now. All Packages for lualatex must be put into after ifluatex right?

Comment: What do you mean with "after `ifluatex`"? To specify your question you should provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Packages like `pstricks` or `auto-pst-pdf` are independent from the test `ifluatex`. Normally the test is used for `fontspec` or `polyglossia`.

Comment: Did you get it to work? If so, how? You can answer your own question, then...

Answer (score 8):

You can't use PSTricks directly with LuaTeX as even in DVI mode you can't get the 'correct' output. As detailed on the [PSTricks website](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=misc/misc#Lua), the way around this is to do a conditional compilation using `auto-pst-pdf` to generate the required graphical elements using pdfTeX in DVI mode:

```
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\documentclass{article}

\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\else
  \usepackage{tgpagella}
  \usepackage{pstricks}
\fi
  \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Hier ein pstricks-Bild}
\begin{pspicture}(5,3)
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=vlines](0,0)(5,3)(3,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

To see how this works, note that when `auto-pst-pdf` runs the auxiliary compiles, it always uses pdfTeX (in DVI mode). Thus the `\ifluatex` conditional will be false and any LuaTeX-specific stuff will be skipped. To get as close as possible appearance-wise, there is therefore a need to use a 'similar' font in the standard run route. Also note that *anything* to do with PSTricks goes in the 'else' branch: that includes additional PSTricks packages and anything else that needs DVI mode.

Comment: I think this answer is partially obsolete. Because recently there are many issues on compiling PSTricks with GhostScript, (according to Herbert) Lua is the recommended tool to process PSTricks.

Comment: `luapstricks` https://ctan.org/pkg/luapstricks is a replacement for GhostScript and will automatically be loaded if one uses `lualatex`. However, some examples from `pst-char` won't work.