# Chemnum with Chemdraw 16.0.1.4 not working

Tags: chemnum

I ran into the problem that in my .eps files generated via ChemDraw 16.0 do not get their tags replaced.
I tried using a .eps file from 2 years ago (because back then everything worked fine) and for this file it worked.

So I generated the same file twice, once using ChemDraw 16.0 and once using Chemdraw 15.0 and only the latter worked.

This is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,                       %% DIN A4-Papier
DIV=calc,                       %% Satzspiegel berechnen
11pt,                          %% Schriftgröße
captions=tableheading,         %% Tabellenüber- statt unterschriften
english%,german,ngerman         %% deutsch als Dokumentsprache, Englisch als zusätzliche
]{scrreprt}                    %% KOMA-Skript Report als Klasse

\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:1}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:2}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:3}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{ChemDraw/CHI-014-CD15.eps}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:1}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:2}
    \replacecmpd{cmpd:3}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{ChemDraw/CHI-014.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[EPS File generated with Chemdraw 16.0](https://www.sendspace.com/file/gjtj4m)

[image: This is what my file looks like]

Can anyone imagine why this occurs or help me out so I can also use ChemDraw 16.0?

Comment: I needed at least 10 reputation for 3 links so [here is](https://www.sendspace.com/file/w8hwo3) the link to the .eps file generated with ChemDraw 15.0

Comment: That's a ChemDraw-problem, not a tex problem. The string "TMP" is only in the 15.0 version but not in the other. So it can't be replaced.

Comment: Okay so whats your suggestion? Sticking with ChemDraw 15?

By the way somebody else already posted that Error back in January [here](http://forums.cambridgesoft.com/messageview.aspx?catid=12&threadid=3521&enterthread=y#bottom) on the PerkinElmer Support Forum

Comment: I don't have chemdraw. Check if there are some options to change the eps export, e.g. the eps-version. Or ask the support of the software.

Comment: @ChristophH. the link to the .eps files no longer works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and it appears that ChemDraw handles text differently depending on how it is entered.

When you create a text box and type into it, it will store it as a string correctly in the EPS.
However, it was (sometimes) automatically putting it into chemical formula mode - so that in TMP1, the 1 was subscript (TMP<sub>1</sub>). Even if you fix this manually, it now saves the `TMP` and `1` separately in the EPS, meaning CHemNum fails to find `TMP1`.

Example of the bottom of an EPS file which works:

```
0 12 0 tx
(TMP)show
0 12 0 tx
(1)show
gr
gr
end
%%Trailer
showpage
```

This can be manually fixed in the EPS file by changing to:

```
0 10 0 tx
(TMP1)show
gr
gr
end
%%Trailer
showpage
```

(I dont know why that 12 changes to a 10, but it seems to when you fix it in ChemDraw).

Alternatively, when making the text box ensure it is in the correct type style to begin with.