# Using chemnum package with Chemdraw 18.2 not working

Tags: chemnum

I have seen multiple people having issues with .eps files generated from later ChemDraw versions losing their text strings, so automatic numbering packages like chemnum and chemstyle don't work.

Has anyone found a solution to this? I am compiling the document in OverLeaf, but I'm pretty sure the issue is on the ChemDraw --> .eps end, because when I open the .eps file in TextEdit and search for the "TMP1" label, or just "TMP", I get 0 hits. Somehow the "TMP1" label is not readable.

Comment: In earlier versions of chemdraw, the "TMP1" was stored in the eps file as a single "word". Probably newer versions split this up into single characters such as other programms tend to do. If that's the case, you could for example use `Z` instead of `TMP1` and `\replacecmpd[tag=Z]{...}` instead of `\replacecmpd{main}` as long as your molecules don't contain zinc or zirconium...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371450/134144 could also be interesting.